# Problems with Eclipse and Android SDK

Tags: 64-bit, android, eclipse, openjdk, shared-library

I installed Eclipse, openjdk6 and downloaded and extracted the sdk manager file.

Now, When I created an Android project I got the following error:

```
2012-06-06 18:44:40 - contactManager] /home/catia/android-sdks/platform-tools/aapt: 
error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: 
No such file or directory
```

And this one when I tried to create an AVD Manager:

```
[2012-06-06 19:00:18 - SDK Manager] /home/catia/android-sdks/tools/mksdcard: error 
while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No 
such file or directory 
[2012-06-06 19:00:18 - SDK Manager] Failed to create the SD card.
[2012-06-06 19:00:18 - SDK Manager] Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder.
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install libstdc++6-4.6-dev [or search on synaptic with libstdc++ ]. and sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev

Comment: @shantanu The problem is *not* that the header files (`-dev` packages) are missing, but that the Android SDK needs the 32-bit versions of the libraries. Header files are only needed for *building software* that relies on a library, not for running pre-built software.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This problem is occurring because the Android SDK is compiled for a 32-bit GNU/Linux system, and your Ubuntu system is a 64-bit GNU/Linux system. The solution should be easy (since Ubuntu fully supports running 32-bit programs on a 64-bit OS)--just install the 32-bit versions of the libraries it needs.

The simplest and easiest way to do this is to install the 32-bit versions of all the most commonly used libraries, by installing the [ia32-libs [image: Install ia32-libs]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ia32-libs) package. You can do this in the Software Center or in the Terminal with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Originally `ia32-libs` was provided because Ubuntu, in its default configuration, didn't support installing 32-bit Ubuntu packages on a 64-bit system. Now that this is fully supported by default, the `ia32-libs` package just causes the same 32-bit packages to be installed on your 64-bit system that would be installed on a minimal 32-bit system. (So for anyone who is worried this might not work now that `multarch` is supported by default: it still works.)

**Source:** [Android/Eclipse Installation on Ubuntu 11.04 - aapt and adb not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056914/android-eclipse-installation-on-ubuntu-11-04-aapt-and-adb-not-working-properly)
**See also:** [Eclipse Android Plugin — libncurses.so.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005907/eclipse-android-plugin-libncurses-so-5)

Comment: This no longer appears to be a solution for Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: @SahasKatta this works http://askubuntu.com/a/165536/1599

Comment: Read @SahasKatta comment before console shot.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10+ the ia32-libs have been replaced by lib32z1, lib32ncurses5, and lib32bz2-1.0 (mesage provided when you try to install ia32-libs). lib32stdc++6 is not included in this list but is also required.

Comment: This answer lead me to what worked for me: "sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0"

Answer (score 55):

If you are using Debian Jessie (or Ubuntu 13.10+), try

`sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6`

Comment: It work well for ubuntu 13.10 64 bit

Comment: Just solved the same problem for me on Linux Mint 16 RC.

Comment: worked for me on brand-new Ubuntu 14.04. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 36):

[This thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16910) was the fix for me.

Specifically, installing this package:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32z1-dev
```

Comment: None of the answers, except this one, worked for me. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm getting a lot of rep for this answer ... thanks ... somehow user 'Squeezle' changed my answer so what is above is not my original post. -1 to the site for allowing my response to be changed by whomever, but +1 to squeezle for posting what looks like a popular answer.

Comment: Only one that worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. Thank you!

Comment: Works perfectly on Debian 8.1.0. I already had lib32stdc++6 so I knew this wasn't the issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 16):

I just ran into this on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. My solution was:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libc6:i386 libgcc1:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libz1:i386
```

Based on the shared libraries required for the aapt tool:

```
$ readelf -d android-sdk-linux/build-tools/20.0.0/aapt | grep -i shared
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [librt.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libz.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me (Ubuntu 14.04 x64). The others donn't.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me: `aptitude install lib32stdc++6`

Comment: This also eliminated a ton of R related errors for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

This worked for me.

Go to **synaptic** --> Search for **lib32z1** --> select both runtime and development
Apply and u r done.

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu >= 13.04 instead of `ia32-libs` you need `libgl1-mesa-dev:i386`

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev:i386
```

Check [Complete Installation Guide for Android SDK / ADT Bundle on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/318246/223150)

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu 15.04, the following was necessary:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
```