# jenkins-maven-android when running throwing the error "android-sdk-linux/platforms" is not a directory"

Tags: android, ubuntu-for-android, maven-3

I start setting up the jenkins-maven-android and i'm facing an issue when running the jenkin job.

- My Machine Details

> $uname -a
>
> Linux development2 3.0.0-12-virtual #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct
>   7 18:19:02 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

- Steps to install the Android SDK in Ubuntu
  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AndroidSDK
  since i'm working on headless env (ssh to client machine) i used following command to install the platform tools

android update sdk --no-ui

- download apache maven and install on 
  http://maven.apache.org/download.html 
  mvn -version output

> root@development2:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools# mvn -version Apache
>   Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 08:44:56+0000) 
>       Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.0.4

```
Java version: 1.6.0_24, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.

Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre Default

locale: en_US,

platform encoding: UTF-8

OS name: "linux",

version: "3.0.0-12-virtual",

arch: "amd64",

family: "unix"

root@development2:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools#
```

- ran the following two command as mention in below

> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
> ```

[Problems with Eclipse and Android SDK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147400/problems-with-eclipse-and-android-sdk)
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

As error suggest i gave the path to android SDK in jenkins build config still im getting the error
clean install -Dandroid.sdk.path=/opt/android-sdk-linux

Can someone help me to resolve this.

Thanks

Error I'm Getting

```
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
message : Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.1.1:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project base-template: Execution default-generate-sources of goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.1.1:generate-sources failed: Path "/opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms" is not a directory. Please provide a proper Android SDK directory path as configuration parameter <sdk><path>...</path></sdk> in the plugin <configuration/>. As an alternative, you may add the parameter to commandline: -Dandroid.sdk.path=... or set environment variable ANDROID_HOME.
cause : Execution default-generate-sources of goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.1.1:generate-sources failed: Path "/opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms" is not a directory. Please provide a proper Android SDK directory path as configuration parameter <sdk><path>...</path></sdk> in the plugin <configuration/>. As an alternative, you may add the parameter to commandline: -Dandroid.sdk.path=... or set environment variable ANDROID_HOME.
Stack trace : 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.1.1:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project base-template: Execution default-generate-sources of goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.1.1:generate-sources failed: Path "/opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms" is not a directory. Please provide a proper Android SDK directory path as configuration parameter <sdk><path>...</path></sdk> in the plugin <configuration/>. As an alternative, you may add the parameter to commandline: -Dandroid.sdk.path=... or set environment variable ANDROID_HOME.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:98)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:64)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-generate-sources of goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.1.1:generate-sources failed: Path "/opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms" is not a directory. Please provide a proper Android SDK directory path as configuration parameter <sdk><path>...</path></sdk> in the plugin <configuration/>. As an alternative, you may add the parameter to commandline: -Dandroid.sdk.path=... or set environment variable ANDROID_HOME.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.InvalidSdkException: Path "/opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms" is not a directory. Please provide a proper Android SDK directory path as configuration parameter <sdk><path>...</path></sdk> in the plugin <configuration/>. As an alternative, you may add the parameter to commandline: -Dandroid.sdk.path=... or set environment variable ANDROID_HOME.
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.AndroidSdk.assertPathIsDirectory(AndroidSdk.java:125)
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.AndroidSdk.getPlatformDirectories(AndroidSdk.java:285)
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.AndroidSdk.findAvailablePlatforms(AndroidSdk.java:260)
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.AndroidSdk.<init>(AndroidSdk.java:80)
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.AbstractAndroidMojo.getAndroidSdk(AbstractAndroidMojo.java:844)
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.generateR(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:329)
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.execute(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:102)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    ... 28 more
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE*
```

- android home Echo
  root@development2:~# echo $ANDROID_HOME
  /opt/android-sdk-linux

Comment: can you paste the output of `echo $ANDROID_HOME`?

Comment: root@development2:~# echo $ANDROID_HOME
/opt/android-sdk-linux, i could not figure it out what's the problem please help

Answer (score 1):

If `/opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms` doesn't exist, it sounds like you have only installed the base SDK without any Android platforms.

That folder should exist, and should normally contain one or more directories like `android-16` (if you've installed the Android 4.1 platform, for example).

Take whichever platform your app is configured to compile against, and pass it to the `android update sdk` tool, like so:

```
android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter android-16
```

Comment: I'v run this command and install the platforms "android update sdk --no-ui" and i can see the following directories  exists in the platforms folder android-2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10/11/12/13/14/15/16, if i do a echo $ANDROID_HOME it show the path root@development2:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms# echo $ANDROID_HOME
/opt/android-sdk-linux", could not figure it out what causing this issue

Comment: i installed the android as a root user,is there any permission issue that jenkin cannot access the platforms folder???

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a permissions issue. Jenkins should not be running as the root user, so probably it can't access those directories.

Answer (score 0):

this is a permission issue,once i gave the permission it's work fine.